# Trying to set the class path in linux

Tags: java

I found the location of my JRE it is

```
/usr/local/jdk1.7.0_03/jre
```

but where are all the class files stored? What should I set the class path to, this?

Also does Java with an empty class path still look in the default directories used during install?

Can jars when launched contain meta data that specifies the class path ahead of time?

Comment: *"what could be causing this?"*  The code and class-path.  Voting to close.

Comment: Should I just delete the question? I still want to know if there are any default location searched for the class path

Comment: I was just trying to give my reasoning for asking it, that's not my full question

Comment: If your application starts with no errors, at least the standard libraries and the jar itself must be on the classpath. Maybe the java program needs additional resources like property files on the classpath. Does the jar runs under windows with a double click?

Comment: I'm running it on linux, but when I've used net beans (on windows) in the past it does

Comment: I had to do some workarounds to get it to open with java in general for linux

Comment: *"that's not my full question"*  I count 3 '?' on this question at the moment.  Better to limit it to 1.  ;)

Comment: I meant to type actual not full, it's very early where I am not and I should be asleep :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Java traces the several directories to find the classes required for a program.This is the sequence of searching:

```
1) <JDK/JRE>/lib
2) <JDK/JRE>/lib/ext
3) Current directory
4) Additional jars or classes with -cp argument while compiling or executing.
```

If it doesn't find any of those directories, then it would simply through `ClassNotFoundException`

```
Can jars when launched contain meta data that specifies the 
class path ahead of time?
```

Ans:Yes. When compiling or building a jar, one could pass several arguments to mark the main class if it's a executable jar and also the `META-INF` of the environment etc.

Please go through the link on `META-INF` information for a jar management.[META-INF Info in Java](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/guide/jar/jar.html#The%20META-INF%20directory)

Comment: Yes, as a java or javac executable it knows those two paths a head of time.